# About well foundedness

Tags: set-theory

I have two models $U$, $N$ and a $\Sigma_0$-embedding $\pi:U\to N$, where $N$ is transitive. Is this enough to prove that $U$ is well founded?

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Suppose that $U\models x_{n+1}\in x_n$, then $\pi(x_{n+1})\in \pi(x_n)$. In particular, any decreasing sequence would cause a decreasing sequence of $\in$ to exist in $N$ and therefore it is impossible.

Note that we didn't actually use the fact that $N$ is transitive, rather we used the fact that $N$ is well-founded, which is implied by transitivity.

(You can also think about this in the sense that any injective order homomorphism to a well-ordered set implies that the original order was well-founded.)